# Understanding Node ReferenceError dumps

Tags: node.js, error-handling, runtime-error

Trying to get a better idea of how to debug by understanding error dumps. For example, I have a reference error as follows:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: title

This error is located at:
    in TimerForm (at ToggleTimerForm.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at ToggleTimerForm.js:42)
    in ToggleableTimerForm (at App.js:54)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:791)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:887)
    in ScrollView (at App.js:53)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at App.js:47)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

* components/TimerForm.js:54:6 in render
- node_modules/react-proxy/modules/createPrototypeProxy.js:44:35 in proxiedMethod
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8811:23 in finishClassComponent
- ... 17 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Instinctively, the first place I look is TimerForm, but then I see that ToggleTimerForm.js is also listed. What does 'in' mean, and what does 'at' mean? Also, why are there so many files listed? What is the significance of them in this error dump?

Would love to get a better idea of how this all works!

Comment: It is the error stack. The error was thrown at ` TimerForm (ToogleTimerForm.js)`, which was being used  `in RCTView (View.js)`, which was being used `in View (ToggleTimerForm.js)`. The names in blue are the function names which are calling one another in same or different js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically just a [call stack](https://github.com/vanng822/pagination), a chain of functions that call one another. Typically you want to look at the latest one for simple errors, but often you may have to go a few levels up the stack to understand the logic.

Note that the call stack may be displayed in different ways, depending on the framework. In this case you are seeing the react call stack and not the vanilla node.js one.